# How to map package level variable value to project parameter in SSIS?

Tags: variables, ssis

I have a SSIS package to load the new customer data from excel file to SQL server. In this package, there is a ROWCOUNT task to hold the number of new customers added daily and show in the script task.

Variable @[User::NEWCUSTOMER] is used to hold the count of new customers and a Project parameter @[$Project::Customer] also in the package.

So, is there any way to map the value of @[User::NEWCUSTOMER] variable which is at Package level to the Project parameter @[$Project::Customer] so that i can use the value of the variable in the other package also?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "map" it so that it passively passes the value from variable to parameter.

You can actively set it in a script task though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the parameter value during the runtime. You could have a table for storing the result for future use.